# Cairo not drawing on top of GtkTreeView

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm attempting to draw on top of a GtkTreeView with cairo by connecting to the `draw` signal.

This code works perfectly for GtkBox, it draws a red rectangle on it:

```java
box.setApplicationPaintable(true);
box.connect("draw", (GUserFunctionCallback) (self, target, data) -> {
    GtkAllocation allocation = tree.getAllocation();
    new CairoContext(target).newOperation()
            .setColor(255,0,0)
            .addRectangle(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height)
            .fill();
});
```

But when I use GtkTreeView with the same code as above it only renders the TreeView, not the red overlay.

Comment: Probably called before the default handler. Have you tried calling `connect_after` instead of `connect`?

Comment: Yeah that works @liberforce , thanks.